# How can I determine if an item occurs in a between 2 dates with possible date exceptions and day of week limits?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a little complicated so I will try my best to explain everything below.  I have searched around a bit for this I am just having trouble getting it all working together.

I have the following tables:

```
Events
----------------
ID int
Name varchar(100)
StartDate datetime
EndDate datetime


EventDaysOfWeek
------------------
EventID int
DayOfWeekNumber int


EventDateExceptions
--------------------
EventID int
ExceptionDate datetime
```

What I need to do is get all events for a month.  But any event could have any number of date exceptions (dates the event doesn't occur on) and events can be set to only run on certain days of the week (ex. only on Tuesdays and Thursdays).  Below is what I have so far for my proc code (obviously not finished) that gets any event between a passed in start and end date which in this case would be the start of the month and end of the month.

```
Declare @first datetime,    
@last datetime  

Set @first = '3/1/2013' --first date in the range being checked
Set @last = '3/31/2013' --last date in the range being checked

select * from events     
where   
(startdate BETWEEN @first AND @last   -- starts in month
or enddate BETWEEN @first AND @last) -- ends in month
or ((startDate <= @first and endDate >= @last )) -- spans the entire date range
```

**Edit:**

Here are some extra details about my question:

- An event runs continuously from the start to the end date
- If a date exception is added then the event will not occur on the date
- The days of week table will determine the days of the week an event occurs (ex. if and event runs Mar. 1 = Mar.31, a day of week could be set to Thursday which would mean the event would only run on Thursdays between the start and end date)

Originally I worded my question wrong.  I am not looking to optimize the code I have to much (Though your suggestions are appreciated) I am looking for help with my query to get it to return all events that occur between a start and end date but also taking into consideration date exceptions and days of week set for the event.

Comment: Consider an event that runs 3 days, but has a 'date exception' on the 2nd day. Should that event still be returned? Does a date exception mean the event is off entirely, or just for that day? If it means just for that day, the event should still be returned unless all of the days are day exceptions? Is an event a continuous occurrence from start to end, or does that mean that the individual days from start to end are components of it? Sorry if this is a complex question, but Im just making sure I understand the question you posed.

Comment: Its okay my post isn't very clear.  If a date exception is added it means the event will not occur only on that specific date.  So if an even runs from march 1 - march 10 and a date exception is added for march 6 it will run every day except march 6th.  It is possible for more then 1 date to be an exception though which in my case could mean all the dates for a month could be added as an exception and in this case it should not show up.  I am not really sure about the second part of your question.  Events are continues between the start and end date.

Comment: But like I said earlier date exceptions can be added to an event which would mean it would not run on that date.  Also when an event is added "Days of Week" can be set so that even though an event runs March 1 - 31 it would only actually occur on the days specified by the days of week (ex only Tuesday and Thursday between the start and end date).   I hope that helps let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, the question is a bit obscure and it doesn't look like your proc addresses your "exceptions" at all, so my guess is you plan to add them later?

as far as your proc and the performance of it (which is the only true question I see)

First, SELECT * is slow. It is always preferred to SELECT only the columns you actually need. Second, the Between operator is generally faster for date ranges than doing a <= >= operation, but granted it isn't always possible to use it.

So:

```
SELECT [just the columns you need]
FROM events     
WHERE (startDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) -- starts in month
or (endDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) -- ends in month
or (startDate <= @start and endDate >= @end) -- spans the month?
```

**EDIT** Here is a complete sql query that should do what you are asking:

```
declare @startdate date = '2013-03-01'
,@enddate date = '2013-04-01'
,@counter int = 0;
declare @DateTable table (SeqDate Date);

declare @Events table (ID int, Name varchar(100), StartDate Date, EndDate Date);
insert into @Events values(1, '1Event', '2013-03-14', '2013-03-16');
insert into @Events values(2, '2Event', '2013-03-01', '2013-03-13');

declare @EventDateException table (EventId int, ExceptionDate Date);
--insert into @EventDateException values (1, '2013-03-14');
insert into @EventDateException values (1, '2013-03-15');
--insert into @EventDateException values (1, '2013-03-16');

declare @EventDaysOfWeek table (EventId int, DayOfWeekNumber int);
insert into @EventDaysOfWeek values (2, 5);
insert into @EventDaysOfWeek values (2, 6);

/* create a table of all days in the series */
while @startdate < @enddate
begin
insert into @DateTable (SeqDate)
select @startdate
set @startdate = dateadd(dd, 1, @startdate)
set @counter = @counter + 1
end;

select distinct ID, Name from 
--select * from 
@Events e
join @DateTable d
on 1 = 1
left join @EventDateException ex
on e.ID = ex.EventId AND ex.ExceptionDate = d.SeqDate
left join @EventDaysOfWeek dow
on e.ID = dow.EventId
where d.SeqDate BETWEEN e.StartDate AND e.EndDate
AND (d.SeqDate <> ex.ExceptionDate OR ex.ExceptionDate IS NULL)
AND (DATEPART(DW,d.SeqDate) = dow.DayOfWeekNumber OR dow.DayOfWeekNumber IS NULL)
```

Comment: I updated my question to be a little bit more detailed.  I also switched to use between.  I will also selected the actual columns in my code I was just simplifying it.

Comment: @brookesmash okay, so if you have an event where all the dates within the specified range are exceptions for that event, you want to exclude it; OR if none of days of week for that event fall within the specified range, you also want to exclude it?

Comment: exactly! Sorry for being so confusing

Comment: okay, that being the case, this is a much more difficult query than what you probably expect, and it may not even be possible in a single query. ie requiring a temp table, counter, iterative etc. it is an interesting problem; let me see what i can come up with.

Comment: Thanks it looks like it works just one question why do you do this 'dow.EventId AND dow.DayOfWeekNumber = DATEPART(DW,d.SeqDate)' in the left join I took it out and it looks like it is still working because you have it in your where statement as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overdoing the logic if your qualifier is "This MUST start at a START point at least at the beginning of the month and CANNOT end on a date of completion AFTER the month is over OR is null you could simplify:

```
Where StartDate >= @Start and (EndDate <= @EndDate or EndDate is not null)
```

When you add multiple predicates (where statements) with OR clauses the engine has to think through all of them.  The faster you can nail down your logic the better.  This may not be what you want but I know with logic you imply certain logic factors here that will be redundant such as:

"Will a startdate always be before an end date on a row?" =

It should so I don't have to worry about using an End Date as a start point.
It also would imply that if I want to get things that 'finished' in the month I will only have to look for the end date in a less than or equal to as the Start Date is always less, thus it does not need to be qualified.

However what if your order or product is in transit and not finished?  Depending on your logic to populate a table with values that could qualify it out if you have nulls.  However some people do not enter rows in their tables till they get everything, I am not aware of your situation.  If you never have nulls you may omit my parentheses and just have:

```
Where StartDate >= @Start and EndDate <= @EndDate
```